# ESP32 programing error (A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet content )

Tags: esp32

I am trying to find the proper model of my esp32 MCU and find out the reason for below errors:

```
esptool.py v3.1-dev
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting........__
Chip is ESP32-D0WDQ6 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: 30:ae:a4:26:6f:44
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet content
A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet content
```

My ESP32 type and the board setting are shown below ([link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32656775273.html)) :

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case where the upload procedure with esptool.py starts successfully but fails as soon as the baud rate is set to the high baud rate selected in Tools menu, select a lower baud rate in Tools menu.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by how certain pins are wired, if pin 12 is high at boot, programming will also fail with this message.